# Drupal 8.5 REST 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: 8

I had a REST resource for a custom entity working in 8.3, but when I try hitting it in 8.5, I get a 406 with `message": "Not acceptable format: json"` in the body.

Here's my config, with json clearly defined as the format:

`langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - basic_auth
    - MY_MODULE
    - serialization
id: entity.MY_ENTITY
plugin_id: 'entity:MY_ENTITY'
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
  formats:
    - json
  authentication:
    - basic_auth`

I've tried stepping through code with Xdebug in PHPStorm, but not having much luck seeing where this is coming from.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add this on the end of your endpoint URL:

`?_format=FORMAT`. So if you want JSON, its `?_format=json`.

This is a new change in 8.5.0 requiring this argument, but I could not locate in the changelogs exactly why it is now required otherwise a 406 is returned.

This same thing happened to all my REST endpoints until I added that.

Comment: This is the issue for the regression, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2937942, which has a few more related ones.

Comment: I've got that _format parameter in there (without it, the error says html is not an accepted format).  It worked fine in 8.3.  8.5 is the first time I've ever seen that error about json being unacceptable.  I'm also not using views, this is in the Drupal core entity REST resource.

Comment: I should also add that I have a custom REST resource that works fine in both 8.3 and 8.5 (with `?_format=json` required for both).

Comment: Yes, mark format json from settings - http://joxi.ru/n2YjVE4iZo9qLA